# Definining specific mapping rule for a field

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

I've started using ORMLite two days ago for refactoring an existing app....
I've some old stored procedure that returns columns with name that don't map 1:1 my dto object but I've managd to use [AliasAttribute] and it works fine.... at the same time I've some column that currently are mapped with some logic... for example

```
//Consider I've a dataset and I'm processing rows

int average = (int)row["AVERAGE"];
if(average > 50)
{
  myDTO.Message = "Warning";
}
else
{
  myDTO.Message = "OK";
}
```

Now we all agree it's not what it should be done at DataLayer but on that 5years old application we do so...is there a way I can tell in my DTO class (as I've done for Alias) to tell how to act when mapping the AVERAGE column?

Another question do ORM performs a trim on string or have I to perform it myself? again on some SP I've got no trim and I get something as "John DOE          " ....now I do a .TrimEnd() when I got the value...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add the message as a property on your dto

```
public class MyDto 
{
    public int Average { get; set; }

    public string Message
    {
        get { return Average > 50 ? "Warning" : "OK"; }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok but in that way I've to create a property that will go over the "wire" (consider a service based model) ... in my case the Average field will never be used on the client....